# It seems that ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP doesn't work correctly

Tags: android

I try to track the system app before updating and I use:

```
public static boolean isSystemApplication(Context ctx, IContent content) {
    android.content.pm.PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    List<android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo app : apps) {
        if (app.packageName.equals(content.getContentPackage())) {
            return (app.sourceDir.startsWith("/system/app/") && ((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP ) != 1));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but it seems that  (app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP ) != 1) returns always true even the system app was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if a system application has update, both `(app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP ) != 0)` and `(app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM ) != 0)` would return true.